# Change ggplot style like python plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using R and i got this type of plot for my data using the ggplot library

[image]

Is it possible to change the style of the plot with one more like this?

[image]

I would like to change the font style and its size to those of python defalt.
I would also like to delete the gray background and make black margins around the graph.

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE for your plot. Otherwise it's much more hassle to provide you with an answer. The fonts can be changed with the `extrafont` package and all the other stuff is pretty easy as well.

Comment: Pablo, please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined themes:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html
especially `theme_classic()`

or you can make your own theme by modifying some elements of the theme:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line color with `geom_line(color = "#1f77b4")`.
Add an horizontal line with `geom_hline(yintercept = 0.05, color = "#d62728")`

(source of color codes : https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps)